# .htaccess add word length and remove %20

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am using .htaccess file to rewrite certain query strings to pretty urls.
Out of which, I am struggling with two certain rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (new-york|nueva-york|nova-york) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (en|es|de|pt|it) 
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?lan=$1&route=product&productcode=$3 [L,QSA]
```

I want the length of product code for the above case to have a max length of 10.

```
https://www.helloworld.com/?route=check&date=&productcode=NYCSNIA%27%20AND%200%20IN%20(SELECT%20SLEEP(21))%20
```

How do i remove these `&` and other `%27%20AND%200%20IN%20(SELECT%20SLEEP(21))%20`?

I want the output for the second case :
https://www.helloworld.com/?route=check&date=&productcode=NYCSNIA

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to limit the length of a request argument on the level of the http server? Typically that is done in your scripting logic, since that is much more flexible.

Comment: I did put a limit on my scripts, but if you see my second argument there are some unwanted characters which I would like to remove.
Thus i want to limit the word length.

Comment: The question remains: _why_ on http server level? And why would you want to treat different characters different?

Comment: btw. to me it is still unclear what comes in and what the expected output should look like....

Comment: @nozzleman:
 www.helloworld.com/index.php?route=product&productcode=NYCSS

Here the lenght of the productcode must be less than or equals to 10.

Comment: @arkascha: checking on http server level will allow to counter security issues like sql injections.

Comment: @EkramulHoque I'd say that is a false sense of security you generate. Such injection vectors could also be ambedded in the first 10 characters. And you have to take care of that thread anyway on scripting level. So what have you gained? Complexity, that's all.